# React express paspport and google authentication redirect after login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, passport.js

I am trying to use google authentication in my react, express App. I set up two callbacks redirect URI on my google auth20 client ID as shown in the attachment. I configured react proxy to redirect to the server whenever a request is made to `/auth/google` or `/api/*` in setupProxy.js because I use creat react app v2. The app redirect fine from the client-side and google authenticate the login user but google keep redirecting to `http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback` after login in the user. I want to redirect to `http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback` i.e. my client uri after the user is successfully login. for example `localhost:3000/surveys` instead of `localhost:5000/surveys`

**My setupProxy.js file content**

```
 const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware')
    module.exports = function (app) {
      app.use(
        ['/auth/google', '/api/*'],
        createProxyMiddleware({
          target: 'http://localhost:5000',
          changeOrigin: true
        })
      )
    }
```

**My Passport and express route handler**

```
const passport = require('passport')
module.exports = app => {
      app.get(
        '/auth/google',
        passport.authenticate('google', {
          scope: ['profile', 'email']
        })
      )
      app.get(
        '/auth/google/callback',
        passport.authenticate('google'),
        (req, res) => {
          res.redirect('/surveys')
        }
      )

      app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
        req.logout()
        res.redirect('/')
      })

      app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.user)
      })
    }
```

**My google auth20 Client ID Settings**
[image]

Authorized redirect URIs
http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback
http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback

As Attached.

Comment: Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the line `changeOrigin: true` in the option object passed in the `createProxyMiddleware` function.